# How to send some values to this MVC Action from javascript?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC Action which accepts a list of values as shown below:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult Events(string[] vals)
        {
            var events = _lcmEventsRepository.FindAllByEventTypeId(vals[0]);

            return Json(events);
        }
```

How to send some values to this Action from javascript?

I'm using the below code but the value which is received at the server side is not in the right format:

```
var eventtypes = ['1', '2'];

 $.ajax({
                url: shouldRepopulateFromAction,
                //data: { vals: JSON.stringify(selectedValues) },
                data: { vals: JSON.stringify(eventtypes) },
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('error!');
                }
            });
```

vals parameter has one member with the value of

```
["1","2"]
```

Comment: Have you tried with `traditional: true,` parameter? and don't use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: nice, t hanks :) - what's the non-traditional way?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do with the JSON.stringify(), serializing the array, is taken care of if you set 'traditional: true'. What this does is sending the array like this:

```
/Events?vals=1&vals=2
```

if you don't set 'traditional: true' the array will be sent like this:

```
/Events?vals%5B%5D=1&vals%5B%5D=2
```

So the solution is this:

```
 var eventtypes = ['1', '2'];

 $.ajax({
                url: shouldRepopulateFromAction,
                data: { vals: eventtypes },
                type: 'GET',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('error!');
                }
            });
```

You should consider using POST when sending arrays to the server.